# How do I write a C program to calculate length of an array using recursion

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive program to find length of array in C language .

although i have seen solutions in python but i couldn't apply them in C.

I wrote a piece of code:

```
int elementcounter(int *arr, int n)
{   
    if(arr[n] == '\0')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
     
        return ( 1+elementcounter(arr, (n+1)));
    }


}
```

But it is not giving correct answers.
i have printed it by:

```
printf("the total elements are %d\n", (elementcounter(arr, 0)-1));
```

Comment: In C, arbitrary arrays don't have a length that can be determined. Exceptions to this are arrays like a C string that are defined to end with a sentinel value (like '\0' or NULL or ...) You need to describe how your array is marked to signify "no more elements beyond here."

Comment: PS: Using recursion would be asking the CPU to warm up unnecessarily... Function calls are not free... An iterative solution (assuming the array does have a terminating value to find) would run faster and the code would be far more conventional. Don't seek to write complexity into code.

Comment: An integer array does not necessarily end with a zero.

Comment: yeah I was just reading the grokking algorithms book and there was an exercise question of this sort

Comment: Although `'\0'` is an _integer_ constant for zero, it is normally only used when the data type is `char` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`) — not when the variable is an `int`.  Then you use `0` instead.

Comment: A bit off topic but.... Answers and other comments have already explained that in general you can't pass an array to a function and have the function calculate the number of elements in the array. It's impossible due to the way arrays are passed in C (i.e. turned into a pointer to first element). But it's worth to mention that you can calculate the number of elements in an array if you do it in the function where the array is defined. Like `int arr[] = {1, 21, 321, 4321}; size_t elements = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];` This will assign the value 4 to  `elements`.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done if you have a specific array-terminator element, like the string null-terminator. This is because once you pass an array to a function all you're left with is a *pointer*. And it's only a pointer to a single value.

If you have a terminator element, then just check for it and if not found call recursively with the index plus one. If the terminator is found return `0`, otherwise return `1` plus the result of the recursive call.

If there is no terminator element in your array, then it's impossible and can't be done using recursion or plain loops.

Also note that unless coded with [tail-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in mind, and the compiler actually doing tail-recursion, you could risk a stack overflow if the array is too long leading to a too deep recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I just edited my question can you please tell me what have I done wrong . This is just a simple integer array.

Comment: User beware... "Dog" has 3 characters, but the "array size" is 4... Does one count the terminator in the size of the array being measured... or not?

Comment: @Ansh Do you have an *explicit* zero at the end of the array? Because that's what I meant by "array-terminator element". You must *explicitly* have such an element, inside the actual array itself, otherwise it's not possible. If you go out of bounds looking for a zero (please use plain `0` for `int` values) then you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am new to coding so I don't really know much but doesn't the array automatically ends with \0 if we dont do anything

Comment: @Ansh No, that's only specific for strings that are created using literal strings or other string functions. Arrays in general doesn't have any terminators. Take for example an array of structure objects, how would that array be "zero" terminated?

Comment: @Fe2O3 yeah that is why i have put -1 in the printf statement but still it doesnt work

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so is it not possible to calculate the length of the array

Comment: @Ansh No it's not really.

Answer (score 1):

When passing an array to a function, without being told how many elements there are in the arry, the only way for the function to not walk off the end of the array is if there is a special (and extra) *sentinel* value marking the end of the array.

I've revised your code somewhat and added some extra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define SENTINEL INT_MIN // an unlikely but not impossible integer value

int elementcounter( int *arr, int n ) {
    return arr[n] == SENTINEL ? 0 : 1 + elementcounter( arr, n+1 );
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 42, 0, 23, 1024, -57, 45678, SENTINEL };

    int n = elementcounter( arr, 0 );

    printf( "# of elements: %d\n(%d really when accounting for the terminator.)\n", n, n+1 );

    printf( "The compiler says there are %d elements in this array.\n", sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

```
# of elements: 6
(7 really when accounting for the terminator.)
The compiler says there are 7 elements in this array.
```

Changing the "bottom of the recursion" return value from 0 to 1 means that the function DOES correctly count the sentinel element, too. It **is** part of the array.

**EDIT:**
Here is an iterative code snippet that doesn't thrash the stack with recursion. The simplest solution is the best solution.

```
    int n = 0;
    while( arr[n] != SENTINEL ) n++;
    n++; // the uncounted sentinel element

    printf( "# of elements: %d\n", n );
```